# Object Casting in C#

Tags: c#

what is the difference as well as the pros and cons between

```
 LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)ctl;
```

and

```
 LinkButton lb = ctl as LinkButton;
```

I tried using the first one and it gives me error,
then I tried the other one with the keyword as, it work just fine.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Have seen this. Must be duplicate. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first is an explicit cast, and the second is a conversion.  If the conversion fails for the `as` keyword, it will simply return `null` instead of throwing an exception.

This is the documentation for each:

- [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
- [as (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

Note in the linked documentation above, they state the `as` keyword does not support user-defined conversions.  +1 to Zxpro :)  This is what a user-defined conversion is:

[User-Defined Conversions Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476.aspx)

Comment: I believe it's also quite important to mention that the `as` operator does not perform any user-defined conversion (implicit or explicit).

Answer (score 9):

My usual guidance on using the `as` operator versus a direct cast are as follows:

1. If the cast **must** succeed (i.e. it would be an error to continue if the cast failed), use a direct cast.
2. If the cast might fail and there needs to be programmatic detection of this, use the `as` operator.

The above is true for reference types.  For value types (like `bool` or `int`), `as` does not work.  In that case, you will need to use an `is` check to do a "safe cast", like this:

```
if (x is int y)
{
   // y is now a int, with the correct value

}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

I do not recommend trying to catch `InvalidCastException`, as this is generally the sign of a programmer error.  Use the guidance above instead.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that casting using the first method throws an exception if it can't cast the object properly (trying to cast the wrong type), whereas using the as keyword will simply set the variable to null if it couldn't cast it properly.

So make sure that if you use the as keyword cast, you check

```
if(lb == null)
    return null; // or throw new Exception()
```

and if you use the () cast, you surround it with

```
try
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)ctl;
}
catch(InvalidCastException ex)
{
    //TODO: Handle Exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second one is called safe cast, which, instead of throwing exception, will put "null" to your variable. So it does NOT work fine, but sets your `LinkButton lb` to null

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88420.aspx) from @Jon Skeet : [What's the difference between cast syntax and using the as operator?](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88420.aspx)