# Which is better - (int)value or value as int?

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Can someone explain the difference to me and which one is better to use? I know in some situations I can only use one or the other.

`(int)value`

`value as int`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is invalid. You can use

```
value as int?
```

if you need to "convert if possible". That's slower than

```
if (value is int)
{
    int x = (int) value;
    ...
}
```

though. That's what you should probably use if you're not confident that `value` is actually an `int`. If, however, your code is such that if `value` isn't an `int`, that represents a bug, then just cast unconditionally:

```
int x = (int) value;
```

If that fails, it will throw an exception - which is generally appropriate for a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I `value as int` will cause a compiler error because `operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type)`. So when dealing with structs, you always use `(int)value` and with Objects, I prefer `obj as SomeType` because it is clearer and more straight to the point, plus it handles exceptions automatically (if an error occurs during casting the operator returns null).

Comment: Not exception, it is a compiler error.

Comment: Yep you're right, I just forgot the correct term, been in Java and Obj-C too long :)