# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query that keep returning this error even though I have the DateTime as DBNullable. The trace indicates that the returned values from the database for the insertdate and deletedate are the issue.

This is the error:

> at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
>
> at System.Convert.ToDateTime(Object value)

```
    public DateTime? insertDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? deleteDate { get; set; }


    public List<Parameters> fraudResults(DataTable dt)
    {

        var convertedList = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             select new Parameters()
                             {
                                 ID = Convert.ToInt32(rw["ID"]),
                                 retailer = Convert.ToString(rw["Retailer"]),
                                 flaggedReason = Convert.ToString(rw["FlaggedReason"]),
                                 insertDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rw["InsertDate"]),
                                 deleteDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rw["DeleteDate"])
                             }).ToList();

        return convertedList;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you change Convert.ToDateTime() to datetime.tryparse () ?

Comment: You can try like this `rw["InsertDate"] == null ? Datetime.Now : Datetime.Parse(rw["InsertDate"])`

Comment: c# does not allow a DateTime to be null!!!  DateTime as DBNullable is not allowed in Net Library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling a DateTime DBNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978815/handling-a-datetime-dbnull)

Comment: Try this: [NotMapped]
        public DateTime data { get { return DateTime.ParseExact(eventdate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); } }

Comment: @Chirag Rupani Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

rw["InsertDate"] == DbNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(rw["InsertDate"].ToString());

Comment: You should also consider just using Dapper : https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

It takes care of most of these issues and it's lightweight and fast