# When to use the "as" keyword and when to use () casting?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

as doesn't throw an exception, but wouldn't it result in a NullPointerException later? doesn't it make it harder to debug?

Comment: You can always check for null after using `as`.

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate, but I can't find the original right now. (Edit: Yay, I was right!)

Comment: sorry guys. Didn't find that when (auto) searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after using the as, you should always check for null.