# Difference between "as" and "cast" keyword in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

The as operator is similar to a cast. But i want to know the difference?
And also i`ve doubt it is operator or keyword? :)

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator

Comment: Just to answer your second question: in C# `as` is a keyword *and* an operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bewds7kc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The as operator is the same as  cast operator except that it yields null on conversion failure instead of throwing an exception

Answer (score 2):

Both are used for casting, however AS will return a null if there is a cast mismatch where as the latter throws an exception. 
AS is an operator.