# If object is SomeType vs. object as SomeType

Tags: c#, object

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)
>   [casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

I know I can do the following:

```
if(someObject is Bar)
{
    Bar b = (Bar)someObject;
    //Use b
}
```

and also:

```
Bar b = someObject as Bar;
if(b != null)
{
    //Use b
}
```

Is one preferable over the other, if I assume I'm just going to reference the `someObject` in another variable?

*EDIT: By preferable, I'm meaning following conventions, performance, chance for bugs, and readability.*

Comment: I'm sure we have been over this more than once ...

Comment: @Jon Skeet @Brain Rasmussen I apologise, they did not appear on the 'related questions' nor on my searching. @digEmAll I'm somewhat new to C#, couldn't I use the second one if I used a nullable Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version has two checks, whereas the second one has only one check.
--> The second one is preferable.