# What is the difference between "object as type" and "((type)object)"?

Tags: c#, object, types, casting, strong-typing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)
>   [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

```
object myObject = "Hello world.";
var myString = myObject as string;
```

---

```
object myObject = "Hello world.";
var myString = (string)myObject;
```

I have seen type conversion done both ways. What is the difference?

Comment: See my article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myString = myObject as string;
```

It only checks the runtime type of `myobject`. If its `string`, only then it cast as `string`, else simply returns `null`.

```
var myString = (string)myObject;
```

This *also* looks for `implicit` conversion to string from the source type. If neither the runtime type is `string`, nor there is `implicit` conversion, then it throws exception.

Read **Item 3: Prefer the `is` or `as` Operators to Casts** from Effective C# by Bill Wagner.

Comment: Does this mean `(string)myInt` would return a string value of myInt but `myInt as string` would return null?

Comment: It looks for explicit conversions, no?

Comment: @Alex: If there is an implicit conversion method from the source type to destination type, then yes, it will return string value of myInt.

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry, let me rephrase: if there is an implicit conversion from the source type to `string`, the cast is superfluous anyway. If there is an `explicit` conversion defined, that is the one that will be used. 'explicit' or 'implicit' isn't really relevant, since defining either one will cause that code to be invoked.

Answer (score 6):

"as" will set the result to `null` if it fails.

Explicit cast will throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: Thanks! I never realized this.

Answer (score 1):

The cast will throw an exception if the object cannot be cast to the target type. `as` will just return `null`.