# Is there a difference between "(Type)abc" and "abc as Type"

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Firstly I am sorry if this is a duplicate, I have tried to google but it is not an easy "google to do"!

Is there a difference (functionally, performance wise, etc) between the following code fragments:

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)someObject;

MyClass myClass = someObject as MyClass;
```

Comment: There you go :[Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Comment: just with exception and without exception

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is a difference!

**as** operator will set variable to **null** if casting fails

Explicit casting will raise exception

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first variant will throw an exception, if it can't cast 'someObject' to 'MyClass'. Whereas the second will then just return null.