# Asp.Net: casting or converting using as

Tags: casting, controls, type-conversion

What do you think about casting or converting using as? For example, 
should I use this one?

```
 CheckBox cbStatus = sender as CheckBox ;
```

Or this one?

```
 CheckBox cbStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
```

Comment: Try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do “as”, then always check for null. If you are sure of the type which is returned, then simply cast it instead of doing “as”. “As” can return null