# Casting an Object is making it become null

Tags: c#, casting, action, func

In a call back like this:

```
 this.Model.LoadStudent(student_key, (o, a) =>
                            {
                                var student = o as Students;
```

If I put a break point on first line, debugger shows me that `"o"` has what I am looking for and also shows me its type which is `"Students"` but as soon as it goes to next line and does the cast, the result is `null`. Why? What is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not casting - you're using the `as` operator. If you instead *actually* cast, I suspect you'll get an exception:

```
var student = (Students) o;
```

I suspect you've actually got multiple types called `Students`, and if you really cast instead of using `as` you'll see the actual type involved.

For example:

```
using System;

namespace Bad
{
    class Students {}

    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            object o = new Good.Students();
            Students cast = (Students) o;
        }
    }
}

namespace Good
{
    class Students {}
}
```

This leads to:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException:
    Unable to cast object of type 'Good.Students' to type 'Bad.Students'.
   at Bad.Test.Main()
```

Note how you get the fully-qualified type names in the exception.

In general, it's a bad idea to use `as` unless you *really* expect that the object may not be of the right type, and usually you check for that afterwards. See [my blog post on the topic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx) for more details.

Comment: You are right Jon, in my case the actual type is saying 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation`1[Students]'  and now throws the exception that can't cast that to "Students"

Comment: Very interesting blog post. Never thought about exceptions like that before.Just saw them as **Bad**.

Answer (score 3):

In that case your object isn't of the **Students** type. Casting in this way won't throw an error if you are casting to the wrong type it will just make the object null.