# Unity - How to respawn a Gameobject after destroy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm Using unity for developing my game. I've created a simple game just like football after scoring a goal the ball should be destroyed and then reappear at its original place.

I've attached this script to my goal object.

```
public GameObject ball;
Vector3 ballPosition = new Vector3 (4.51f,0.10f,-3.78f);

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)  
    {

        StartCoroutine ("RespwanBall");

    }

IEnumerator RespwanBall() {

    GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate (ball, ballPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    Destroy (ball.gameObject);

    yield return null;

}
```

But it works only for the first time. and then After second destroy it gives an error saying that the object is already deleted and you are trying to access a deleted object or something like that. And if I use the destroy function in the `OntriggerEnter` function it gives the same error during the first collision.

How can I do it? Please Help.

ThankYou.

Comment: Lots of things wrong with this... 1. `ball.GameObject` should just be `ball` 2. You're casting the result from `Instantiate` twice 3. There's no reason for `RespwanBall` to be a coroutine 4. You never set `ball` to `clone` 5. You mispelled 'Respawn' :)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanx a lot for pointing out all those mistakes. I really should work on it. Thanx a lot.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Can you pls elaborate the correction for the 4th step. ThankYou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the deleted object because you attached the script to the goal and you are always deleting the ball, and your clone never becomes the ball (so it's always the same ball).

Your script would work if it was attached to the ball, because in this case the `ball` would be itself, therefore the destruction method would always be activated in the active ball.

If you want to attach it to the goal, make sure to update your clone to be the active ball:

```
IEnumerator RespwanBall() {
    Destroy (ball.gameObject);
    ball = (GameObject)Instantiate (ball, ballPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    yield return null;
}
```

Also, BlueRaja's comments are important things that you could use to improve your code:

1. `ball.GameObject` could just be `ball`, since `ball` *is* a `GameObject`;
2. You're casting the result from Instantiate twice, check [this question to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator) about it;
3. At least with this piece of code, there's no reason for RespwanBall to be a coroutine;
4. You mispelled 'Respawn'.

Comment: @BlueRaja thanks for editing, I just copied his code and didn't notice!

Comment: I have tried your code with the corrections suggested by BlueRaja. And now its not even destroying the object.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment. I have tried your code and now its giving me the same error after first respawn. Attached it to the goal object.

Comment: It worked when I attached it to the ball. Thanks, but still curious to know the methods if it is attached to the goal.

Comment: @AshishBeuwria If you want to attach it to the goal, make sure to update your clone to be the active ball, by doing ball = (GameObject) Instantiate...

Comment: Where should i do it? In the onTriggerEnter() or Update()

Comment: Thats creating two instances of ball. One is ball(clone) and other is ball(clone)(clone)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46666/discussion-between-ashish-beuwria-and-roberto)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try respawning the object by using this script -




using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class copy : MonoBehaviour
{




     [SerializeField]
    private GameObject prefab = null; // assign Cube prefab to this in Editor
    void Start()
    {
        // no need for a local prefab variable, nor a call to Resources.Load();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, i * 10, 0), Quaternion.identity); // you can directly assign position in Instantiate
        }
    }

}
```