# UNITY SCRIPTS:spawn in same location after getting destroyed(after 3 seconds)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hey does anyone knows how to make a C# script for object to re spawn after getting destroyed by a bullet

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504466/unity-how-to-respawn-a-gameobject-after-destroy

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work for my scene, thank you

Comment: `doesn't work` is not a very strong argument. Why exactly does it not work for you?

Comment: it doesn't have any code for explaining only react for my bullet and re spawn time after getting destroyed

Answer (score 1):

There are multible ways to archive this.

Note that you can also work completely without Coroutine but this usually sucks

```c#
private float timer;

private bool isRespawning;
private GameObject clone;

private void DestroyObject(GameObject obj)
{
    isRespawning = true;
    timer = 3f;

    // first make a clone of the current Object
    var clone = Instantiate(obj, obj.transform.position, obj.transform.rotation, objtransform.parent);

    // disable the clone
    clone.SetActive(false);

    // Destroy the original
    Destroy(obj);
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Mathf.Approximately(timer,0f)) return;

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer > 0) return;

    // Set the clone active
    clone.SetActive(true);
    timer = 0;
}
```

---

Simplier would be a Coroutine:

```
private void DestroyAndRespawn(GameObject obj)
{
    StartCoroutine(DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(obj));
}

private IEnumerator DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(GameObject obj)
{
    // first make a clone of the current Object
    var clone = Instantiate(obj, obj.transform.position, obj.transform.rotation, objtransform.parent);

    // disable the clone
    clone.SetActive(false);

    // Destroy the original
    Destroy(obj);

    // Wait 3 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    // Set the clone active
    clone.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

But why should you destroy the object and respawn it? You can simply only disable and later re enable it

```
private void DestroyAndRespawn(GameObject obj)
{
    StartCoroutine(DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(obj));
}

private IEnumerator DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(GameObject obj)
{
    // disable the obj
    obj.SetActive(false);

    // Wait 3 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    // Set the objactive
    obj.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

**Update**

Since you want to call this on collision:

You will need another GameObject that works as a Manager for the respawning / enabling, disabling since you can not just attach that script to the object you disable -> would also disable the script and never re-enable the object.

1. Create a new empty GameObject e.g. called "RespawnManager"
2. Create a new Script RespawnManager.cs:

   ```
   public class RespawnManager : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public static RespawnManager Singleton;

       private void Awake()
       {
           if(Singleton)
           {
               enabled = false;
               return;
           }

           Singleton = this;
       }

       private void DestroyAndRespawn(GameObject obj)
       {
           StartCoroutine(DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(obj));
       }

       private IEnumerator DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(GameObject obj)
       {
           // disable the obj
           obj.SetActive(false);

           // Wait 3 seconds
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

           // Set the objactive
           obj.SetActive(true);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Than you can call it on collision like

   ```
   OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj)
   {
       if (obj.gameObject.name != "bullet") return;

       // pass this GameObject to the manager
       RespawnManager.Singleton.DestroyAndRespawn(gameObject);
   }
   ```

Comment: how to make sure it acts only after getting hit by the bullet

Comment: I leave this as a homework for you. https://answers.unity.com/questions/372595/how-to-detect-collisions-in-c.html

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class destroy : MonoBehaviour
{

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
  
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {
  
 }

 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj)
 {
  if (obj.gameObject.name == "bullet")
  {
   Destroy (gameObject);
            

        }
}

}

Comment: where should i attach your original code to, object or and empty game object

Comment: well if you would attach this code to the object itself you are going to destroy it would probably not be a good idea, right? If you rather use the last section with just disabling the object than you could put the code directly in the `OnCollisionEnter` method

Comment: like how?|
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj)
    {
        if (obj.gameObject.name == "bullet")
        {
            // disable the obj
            obj.SetActive(false);

            // Wait 3 seconds
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

            // Set the objactive
            obj.SetActive(true);


        }

Comment: No, calling `DestroyAndRespawn`, the method I posted as answer. Please see my last section "Update".

Comment: like this??
 // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator DestroyAndRespawnRoutine(GameObject obj)
    {
        if (obj.gameObject.name == "bullet")
        {
            // disable the obj
            obj.SetActive(false);

            // Wait 3 seconds
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

            // Set the objactive
            obj.SetActive(true);


        }
    }

Comment: no wait I just noticed that would maybe also not work because you would also disable the script itself -> your object wouldn't be re-enabled. You have to use a seperate Manager object to controll that respawn

Comment: with the original script?

Comment: empty game object?

Comment: please see my Update

Comment: how to add the enemy object to the RespawnManager.cs

Comment: `RespawnManager .Singleton.DestroyAndRespawn(gameObject);` see my update. I didn't read well and accidently passed in the bullet instead of the hit object

Comment: do i have to attach to the empty game object or object,

Comment: because spawn script doesn't have any variable to explain the object in my scene

Comment: finally got it i need  to change your script little bit then it was ok . thanks man

Comment: needed to erase the  'return'  part (enabled = false;
            return;)

Comment: that part makes actually only sure, you don't have multible Managers running at the same time ... so it shoudl work with it

Answer (score 0):

Set object `active` to False. using

```
gameobject.SetActive(false);
```

And you can use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) to do this.

Comment: To be fair the question is very bad. But could you please elaborate this a bit in order to make this post a valid complete answer. Currently it is somewhere inbetween a comment and an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Destroy(yourObject);`, the object does get removed and you loose access.
You could make your Object into a prefab and spawn it where you want by using `GameObject obj = Instantiate(...);`
Obj contains the reference to the new spawned object and not to the prefab, which means you can later again use `Destroy(obj);`

Comment: To be fair the question is very bad. But the OP actually wants it the other way round: Destroy an object -> remember its position -> (re)Spawn at this position .... whatever this means

Comment: If op wants to use the exact same obj, then he needs to use setActive as the other answers says and he cannot use Destroy.