# What does ((Control)name) mean?

Tags: c#, loops, controls

I have been using this `((Control)name)` for some time, but I don't understand the construction of the brackets and what that means.

For example, when I'm looping through controls on a page, I do so like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Booking_Quote.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Panel)
    {

        foreach (Control tb in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (tb is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)tb).Text = "Hello world";

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking to know what `((TextBox)tb)` means.

Comment: It is an explicit type conversation from `Control` to `TextBox`. You can read [Explicit Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s682k58%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Since `TextBox` inherited from `Control`, it is ok to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: and it's needed because not all `Control` objects have a `Text`property for example, so before accessing any specific property you've got to indicate what is the exact type of your quite generic `Control` object.

Comment: ((TextBox)tb) is the old "C" style of casting.  Here's a link that discusses this method of casting and the use of the "as" for casting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator

Comment: Its customary to upvote your answer. (as well as others you found helpful) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you're casting your object to `TextBox` (or `Control`)

In your example, you wrote this:

```
if (tb is TextBox)
{
   ((TextBox)tb).Text = "Hello world";
}
```

If `tb` is a `TextBox`, then you cast your object to a `TextBox` to have access to its methods and set values as you want.

You can do a explicit cast, which will throw an exception if the cast fails, OR you can convert your object, using the [`as operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx), which will return `null` if the conversion fails, like this:

```
(tb as TextBox).Text = "Hello world";
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a type cast to let the compiler know that the `tb` object is a actually a `TextBox` object.

Answer (score 0):

It is the cast operator. In this code:

```
if (tb is TextBox)
{
    ((TextBox)tb).Text = "Hello world";
}
```

You're casting `tb` to `TextBox` type, to get access to the `Text` property. Without the cast it would remain of `Control` type and the `Text` property would not be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

As a `Control` may not have a Text property, it first checks if the current `Control tb` is a `TextBox` via the line

```
if (tb is TextBox)
{
....
}
```

Then before using the `Control tb` as a `TextBox` you first need to explicitly cast it to `TextBox` in order to access the Text property.

You do this by preceding a variable with a `Type` object within parentheses, in this case `(TextBox) tb`

See [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)