# Downcasting in Settings Class - Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio v12.0 and looking at the Settings.Designer.cs file in the Solution Explorer. In the Properties namespace, the Settings derived class is created from ApplicationSettingsBase class like so:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
```

In the class, this line of code has me confused:

```
private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));
```

This is an example of downcasting, I believe. I'm not clear why this is necessary. Why not just create an instance of Settings since it's already defined as inheriting the base?

Here's a longer snippet:

```
namespace ConfigMgrTest.Properties {

[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {   
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

...rest of the namespace...
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line:

```
Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));
```

is equivalent to saying:

```
Settings s1 = new Settings();
SettingsBase synchronizedBaseSettings = global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(s1);
Settings settings = (Settings)synchronizedBaseSettings;
```

So the cast is required because `ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized` returns `SettingsBase` type. And [`ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase.synchronized%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called to make the settings object threadsafe. Otherwise you would have to: a) define `defaultInstance` as `SettingsBase` or b) do not call `ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized` and risk threading issues.

I guess nowadays the method `ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized` would be declared as a generic like this:

```
public static TSettings Synchronized<TSettings> (TSettings settingsBase) where TSettings: SettingsBase
```

But this class is probably older than generics in c# ;).

Comment: Many thanks, this nails it. BTW, if the casting notation used here a relic? I can only seem to find examples using the "as" keyword.

Comment: @TimBostwick Not really, those operators (explicit cast and 'as') behave differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator