# Given a TabPage, find its TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have an instance of a `TabPage`.

I want to ask that `TabPage`:

> "Who's your TabControl?"

That is, I wish to query a `TabPage` to get a reference to the `TabControl` that contains it.

Comment: Hmm, "handle"...  Let's assume you meant reference, cast its Parent property to (TabControl).

Comment: What is `Tabpage.Parent`?

Comment: A "handle" to a TabPage?  Are you working with your own app?...or an external app?  Do you really mean a handle, or a reference?  Why not just use the Parent() property?

Comment: "Reference", not "handle". I am working of 4 different platforms simultaneously, each using different terms, so I got my terms confused. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast the [`Tabpage.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) to a `TabControl`:

```
TabControl parent = tabpage.Parent as TabControl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Except that I would prefer (TabControl)tabpage.Parent (Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)