# Converter does not work after calling OnPropertyChanged

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, ivalueconverter

I have been trying to make this work for a while with no success.
I have a converter to pretty print dates on the page. Convert function is as follows;

```
class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Nullable<int> _date = value as Nullable<int>;

        if (!_date.HasValue)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter as String))
        {
            if (parameter.Equals("EDITED"))
                return "edited " + UtilityFunctions.formatUnixTime(_date.Value);
        }

        return UtilityFunctions.formatUnixTime(_date.Value);
    }
}
```

In XAML part I am using this converter by passing a property of a property to it.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Wiki.EditDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, ConverterParameter=EDITED}" />
```

My ModelView extends BindableBase and whenever I update Wiki property, I call SetProperty which in return calls OnPropertyChanged for Wiki property.

If I try to show the date without a converter, it works fine.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Wiki.EditDate}" />
```

I am using this converter in other parts of my projects so I believe it is not the cause of the problem.

What might be the cause of this problem?

Thanks for any helps...

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check what happens? Have you defined resource with a key *DateConverter*, `<convClass:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter"/>`? Have you looked at output window while debugging - are there any exceptions?

Comment: @Romasz Yes, I have debugged the converter and the value of _date is null. There are no binding errors in the output console. Resource is also defined, and I am currently using this converter on another page. The difference is on this page I am loading the value from a web API using an async method. So when the page opens the value is not set yet.

Comment: So this means that the breakpoint in the converter is being hit, is that right? Can you check what's the value of `value` not `_data`?

Comment: @Romasz thanks for your feedback. The value was formatted ("2014-06-03 00:56:21") and was not an int hence the conversion to Nullable<int> failed. Now the question is why didn't the conversion throw an exception? By the way, can you write this as an answer with some explanation so that I can mark it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the answer I've explained why convecrsion doesn't throw an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in discussion and debugging - the problem was that the *value* passed to converter was wrong - `"2014-06-03 00:56:21"`.

Such value can't be coverted to *int*, and because you are using `as`:

```cs
Nullable<int> _date = value as Nullable<int>;
```

there won't be exception thrown. Instead of exception you have `null` (*as* doesn't throw InvalidCastException).
If you would use cast:

```cs
Nullable<int> _date = (Nullable<int>)value;
```

then you would have an exception. Some more information you will surely find on SO - [for example this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132467/2681948).