# Casting User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, user-controls

In winforms I want to cast a `UserControl` as a specific user control so I have access to its public members.

My setup is something like this:

```
enum ePage
{
    Setup,
    AddMorePagesHere
}

var _pages = new List<UserControl>();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    _pages.Add(new ucSetup());
    _pages.Add(new ucAddMorePagesHere());
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Now is there a difference between

```
(_pages[(int)ePage.Setup] as ucSetup).SetupMethod();
```

and

```
((ucSetup)_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]).SetupMethod();
```

How would you do it?

Comment: In terms of functionality, as long as the control isn't null, there's really no difference. If the control _is_ null, you'll get an exception anyways on the call to `SetupMethod`. Stylistically it's up to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Comment: If the object isn't a `ucSetup` the difference would be the exception.  It would be a null reference exception for the first one and a cast exception for the second.  But why don't you just create a field for each control instead of putting them into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference that matters to you is that:

```
(_pages[(int)ePage.Setup] as usSetup).SetupMethod();
```

might throw a `NullReferenceException` if the control you're casting is not `usSetup`, as the `as` operator then returns `null`.

while the

```
((ucSetup)_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]).SetupMethod();
```

might throw an `InvalidCastException`.

As long as you're sure that you're casting the right object, you're safe to use either.

Actually, I'd ensure that there's really only one control per `ePage` value, so I'd use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
Dictionary<ePage, UserControl> pages = new ...;
pages[ePage.Setup] = new usSetup();
pages[ePage.Other] = new ...;

var page = pages[ePage.Setup] as usSetup;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

## "As" cast

```
(_pages[(int)ePage.Setup] as usSetup).SetupMethod();
```

If `_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]` is not `usSetup`, you will get `NullReferenceException` here, because `(_pages[(int)ePage.Setup] as usSetup)` will return null.

## Direct cast

```
((ucSetup)_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]).SetupMethod();
```

If `_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]` is not `usSetup`, you will get `InvalidCastException` here.

Other than that, no differences.

By the way, I encourage you to follow .NET naming guidelines. Your classes should be named `UCSetup` (or `UcSetup`) and `UCAddMorePagesHere` (or `UcAddMorePagesHere`).

## Alternative

You can simplify your code if you do the following:

```
public abstract class SetupPage : UserControl
{
    public abstract void SetupMethod();
}  

public class UcSetup : SetupPage
{
    public override void SetupMethod()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}

public class UcAddMorePagesHere : SetupPage
{
    public override void SetupMethod()
    {
         // Do something here
    }
}
```

Then, instead of keeping list of `UserControl`'s, keep list of `SetupPage`'s

```
var _pages = new List<SetupPage>();
```

You will be able to call your method without a cast:

```
_pages[(int)ePage.Setup].SetupMethod();
```

Comment: Oh, user control inheritance... I'd actually not create a base control, but an interface `ISetupPage` and have that implemented. But as far as I understand the OP, not all the user controls actually contain the `SetupMethod` method.

Comment: I already have an interface like @Thorsten Dittmar suggest and `SetupMethod` is unique to a single user control.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference between two lines of code you've shown.

But first one gives you little more flexibility and ability to check if `_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]` is `usSetup` to prevent `NullReferenceException`.

Like this:

```
var x = _pages[(int)ePage.Setup] as usSetup;
if (x != null)
    x.SetupMethod();
```

In  your second case you can't do such a check and it will be cast exception if `_pages[(int)ePage.Setup]` has type incompatible with `usSetup`.