# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync Throwing Null Object Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nullreferenceexception, owin

`AccountController.cs` houses the `AccountController` class. The `Login` method of that class is failing. Specifically,

```cs
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
    model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

within the `Login` method is throwing `System.NullReferenceException`.

I've verified that `model.Email`, `model.Password`, and `model.RememberMe` are not null. The next step is to dig in to `SignInManager`, which is an object on `AccountController` of type `ApplicationSignInManager`. The `get` accessor for `SignInManager`, which is called from the line above, was

```cs
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ??
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    // private set...
}
```

which I rewrote as

```cs
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        var c = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        var m = c.Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        return _signInManager ?? m;
    }
    // private set...
}
```

to debug and make sure that the `get` accessor was not returning `null`. It's not returning `null`. This tells me that something required inside `PasswordSignInAsync` is `null`.

I've looked at [the source](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.2.0-alpha1-140725/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin) of `PasswordSignInAsync` and it does a pretty good job of guarding against null reference errors. I've also dug deeper into the methods called by `PasswordSignInAsync`. I simply don't see what could be throwing a null reference error.

The stack trace from the error is pretty cryptic, and I don't see anything in it that helps. But for the sake of completeness, here it is:

```cs
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +2112
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +123
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +408
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter.GetResult() +63
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInOrTwoFactor>d__23.MoveNext() +2055
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +68
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +1828
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
ApexRemingtonExternal.Controllers.<Login>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\me\sc\project\Controllers\AccountController.cs:91
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651688
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I'd appreciate any help or guidance on what could be causing this `NullReferenceException`. Please let me know if I can add more detail (or remove some (lol!)). This is my and my company's first MVC project, so I'm sure I've broken something.

**Edit**

I should add that I stripped out Entity Framework from the project in favor of LINQ to SQL, which is what we rely on in all of our other projects. That means that I've had to implement my own versions of IUserStore, IRoleStore, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is usually my wont, the issue had nothing to do with the symptom. Of course `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` isn't broken. It was my code that was broken. That makes this question moot, which begs me to delete the question.

There is, however, a lesson to be learned here. In my case it was the `as` keyword. Having abandoned EF, as mentioned in the edit, I had to supply implementations of several interfaces. One method I had to supply is `GetRolesAsync`, which returns `Task<IList<String>>` (in my case). I've never dealt with `IList`. Turns out `as` is what I needed. But I was trying to cast an `IQueryable` to an `IList`, which doesn't work. The result: `as` simply returns `null`. Thanks, `as`. That's useful.

Yeah. I'll probably delete this question.

Comment: Don't delete! I just got the same error, found this, and it helped me realize, "the issue had nothing to do with the symptom", which would have saved me a deal of time. Mine ended up being a null reference exception hidden by the exception you encountered.

Comment: Hey Jeff, fwiw that's the difference between `as` vs a direct cast (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/132467/1252541)).

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes (especially if you update `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`) you can forgot to add line

`app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);`

to method `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` in *App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs*
After including this everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

A little late in the game, but I encountered this error today and found out that the cause of the null reference exception is the null property within ApplicationUser.

This happens when you create custom claims within your Applicationuser. 
When you call `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` it will GenerateUserIdentity and that will include your custom claims. Any null objects in there will throw NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION.

To show some sample code (please see comments):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...//some additional properties goes here

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        //my custom claims
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("FirstName", FirstName.ToString()),
            new Claim("MiddleName", MiddleName.ToString()),
            new Claim("LastName", LastName.ToString()),
            new Claim("Position", Position.ToString()) //if Position is NULL, it will throw null reference exception
        };

        userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help somebody in the future.

Comment: I added an additional property to my identity model and four hours of frustration let me to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the data!

I have manually set the value of `TwoFactorEnabled` to true in my **test** Database, and for that specific user `PhoneNumber` was null and `PhoneNumberConfirmed` was set to false.
Inserting a value to `PhoneNumber` and marking `PhoneNumberConfirmed` as true made the exception go away.