# Why Doesn't MemoryCache throw an InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, caching, casting

I'm working with a library which contains some 'cacheHelper' functions which act as a wrapper for bits of the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace.

For example:

```
public bool IsInCache(string keyname){
    return MemoryCache[keyname] != null;
}

public static void SaveToCache(string cacheKey, object savedItem, 
                               DateTime absoluteExpiration)
{
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        AbsoluteExpiration = absoluteExpiration,
        RemovedCallback = CacheEntryRemovedCallback
    };

    MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, savedItem, policy);
}
```

All fairly standard stuff. We also have a method to retrieve cached objects:

```
public static T GetFromCache<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
{
    return MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as T;
}
```

I found that if I save an object to the cache as an object of type X and then try and retrieve it from the cache, mistakenly, as an object of type Y, `MemoryCache.Default[cachekey]` returns null and no exception is thrown. I was expecting something like an `InvalidCastException`. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You're using the "as" keyword. "as" will either convert the type, or if it's incompatible it'll return a null. If you want an exception then use a cast "(T)" and it'll error.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator

Comment: [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) for `as`

Comment: Thanks for the links, very illuminating. And of course now I'm struggling to understand why anyone would ever use anything other than an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `as` it sets the object to `null` when the cast fails, this is why you also had to add the `where T : class` to be able to use `as` because you can't use `as` on a `struct`. To get a `InvalidCastException` you must do a direct cast.

```
public static T GetFromCache<T>(string cacheKey) //The "where T : class" is no longer needed
{
    return (T)MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey];
}
```

Comment: Ah. * sound of penny dropping *. Thanks, this something I didn't look at carefully when I switched from java to c#. 

Follow-up question: in this scenario, where the code is being accessed as part of a library, do you think it better practice to use a direct cast as opposed to `as`? In my particular case it took an uncomfortably long time to see my mistake - an exception message would have been helpful.

Comment: It depends on the library. Whatever you do, just make sure to specify it in the documentation.