# Specified cast is not valid when casting from int32 to int16

Tags: c#

Convert.ToInt16(row["INT"] as Int16?); returns 0
and (Int16)row["INT"]; throws an exception Specified cast is not valid.

```
    private DataTable GetTableWithValue()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
            new DataColumn("INT", typeof(Int32)),
            new DataColumn("STRING", typeof(string )),
            new DataColumn("DATETIME", typeof(DateTime )),
            new DataColumn("BOOLEAN", typeof(bool)),
        });

        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());

        dt.Rows[0][0] = 10;
        dt.Rows[0][1] = "Babu";
        dt.Rows[0][2] = DateTime.Now;
        dt.Rows[0][3] = true;
        return dt;
    }


        dt = GetTableWithValue();
        row = dt.Rows[0];


        int? INT = (row["INT"] as int?); //10
        Int16? INT16 = Convert.ToInt16(row["INT"] as Int16?); //0
        Int16 = (Int16)row["INT"]; //Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: if value of row["INT"] is null then  (Int16)row["INT"] code will not handle. Convert.ToInt16() takes argument as an object and will not throw null expcetion

Comment: Does the last line  incorrect ?

 Int16 = (Int16)row["INT"]; //Specified cast is not valid. 

i think it should be 
 INT16 = (Int16)row["INT"]; //Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: if you had done `Convert.ToInt16(row["INT"] as int?)` or even just `Convert.ToInt16(row["INT"])` your 2nd line would have worked. it is the `as Int16` that is breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

`row["INT"] as Int16?` returns `null` when either the provided value within the row *is* zero, or when the value from the row is not castable to `Int16` (for example if the content was `"zero"`). `Convert.ToInt16(null)` now returns `zero`.

However the "direct" cast `(Int16) myValue` throws an exception when the cast fails. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator) for more details

Anyway in your code you´re trying to cast an `Nullable<int>` to `Int16` which is obviously not possible. You can however use the nullables *value*, which *is* an  `int`:

```
Int16 result = ((int?)row["INT"]).Value;
```

EDIT: A quite better aproach would be to use [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9hh1awhy(v=vs.110).aspx) which won´t throw an exception if parsing fails but simply returns `false`:

```
Int16 result;
if (Int16.TryParse(row["INT"].ToString(), out result))  
{
    // do something with result
}
```