# Unable to get dynamic textbox text in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I created the dynamic textboxes and placed in div on Webpage. But I am unable to read the text in the created textboxes.
For Creating I used below code (Sample).
This is my design code in .aspx

```
<div ID="divQtn" runat="server">

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
 txt.ID="txt"+i.ToString();
 txt.Attributes.Add("runat","server");
 divQtn.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

For Reading text from textbox:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 string txtID = "txt"+i.ToString();
 TextBox txt = (TextBox)divQtn.FindControl(txtID);
 string txtData = txt.Text;
}
```

I am getting txt as Null.

Comment: When reading the values, what is in `divQtn.Controls`?  Where in the overall page life cycle are you performing either of these operations?  Are the form values themselves included in the `Request`?

Comment: divQtn.Controls getting Count as '1' and {InnerText="\r\n\r\n                   "} @David

Comment: are you are getting null on this line `string txtData = txt.Text;` ? because i think you should get an error on this line `TextBox txt = (TextBox)divQtn.FindControl(txtID);` if the textbox not found

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic controls in ASP.NET Web Form are a little bit tricky. You will need to reload them back with same id inside ***Page_Init*** (or Page_Load) event.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" 
   OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateDynamicControls();
}

private void CreateDynamicControls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + i;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<string> data = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string txtID = "txt" + i;
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl(txtID);
        data.Add(txt.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following ? :

```
TextBox txt = divQtn.FindControl(txtID) as TextBox; 
string txtData = txt.Text.ToString();
```

or that should be work

```
String sValue=Request.Form["ID HERE"];
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply, I have tried this already. I got as txt as Null.

Comment: why do you think `as` might solve the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/132467/20126

Comment: that's a c# bro, if u close and reopen that sometimes work, sometimes doesn't work. I think thats will be work "String sValue=Request.Form["ID HERE"] ;"

Comment: @MelihYilman String sValue=Request.Form["ID HERE"] ; returning value as Null

Comment: Request.Form has my dynamic textbox controls. But, not getting the value in the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

2nd option is u can add event handler like a that:

```
 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    //add the event handler here
    txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(System.EventHandler(this.txt_TextChanged));

string yourtext;

private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Comment: Bro, I have n(dynamic) numbers of textboxes. while saving I need individual textbox text. @Melihyilman Thanks.