# Datagridview value being stored as Null

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview being populated by a database, when trying to store the values in the back end, the string values are being stored but the numeric values are being store as null or "" even when using different datatypes.

```
        string aa = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value as string;
        string ab = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value as string;
        double? ac = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value as double?;
        string ad = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value as string;
        string ae = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value as string;

        MessageBox.Show(aa + " " + ab + " " +  ac + " " + ad + " " + ae);
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks

EDIT: Ive just noticed, the last 3 columns are all numeric values in the DB, maybe it has something to do with that. Maybe you need to do a different type of casting?

Comment: Could be just the image, but isn't the third (`[2]`) column empty? Meaning your `double? ac` would be on `Cells[3]`?

Comment: Yes thats correct. However, I just tested it on a column with data and it still doesnt work

Comment: why not just use `string ad = datagridview1.rows[0].cells[3].value.tostring();`?

Comment: Yes, you must use cast to the proper type. Or use `ToString()` method. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132467/5045688).