# Casting Generic Types - Why does a direct cast with parenthesis "()" give a compile-error, but casting with the "as"-keyword works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, generic-type-argument

I needed to cast a generic type deriving from `UnityEngine.Object` into `UnityEngine.AudioClip`, but I was having this error all the time:

**Error Message:**

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'T[]' to 'UnityEngine.AudioClip[]'

And I was baffled, cause `AudioClip` derives from `Object`, so it shouldn't be an issue to cast to it.

So the ***Example Code 1*** below is how my code was when I got the error. Then I solved the error by changing the code to the one in ***Example Code 2***.

So my question is:

Why did a direct cast (ie. using parenthesis) NOT work, but casting using the `as`-keyword did?

I want to understand why *Example Code 2* works. I've looked at the "[Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)"-answer, but I don't understand how that would be related to this issue. So any help or explanation as to why this works the way it does would be really appreciated.

---

**Example Code 1: Direct Cast (ie. using Parenthesis)**

```
private void UpdateAudioClipsOnDragAndDrop<T>(T[] draggedObjects) where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    audioClips = (AudioClip[])draggedObjects;
}
```

**Example Code 2: Cast using the "`as`"-keyword**

```
private void UpdateAudioClipsOnDragAndDrop<T>(T[] draggedObjects) where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    audioClips = draggedObjects as AudioClip[];
}
```

---

[Here's also a Screenshot of the Error in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYaT0.png)

Comment: I know this is not related to your immediate question, but why can't you just accept a `AudioClip[]` as the parameter?

Comment: Since your method accepts `T` where `T` is `UnityEngine.Object`, you can pass in any type that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object`. So if you were to pass in an array of [UnityEngine.Avatar](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Avatar.html), what would you expect to happen when `audioClips = (AudioClip[])draggedObjects` executes?

Comment: This is actually a really good question. It made me learn something new - that `as` and the cast operator differs in an aspect that I didn't know before. @devNull That doesn't explain why `as` doesn't produce a compile time error.

Comment: @Sweeper I can't accept `AudioClip[]` as a parameter cause I want the user to be able to make their own custom implementation of this method - if they'd like to. 

This method is just going to be called in a highly controlled manner, ie. whenever someone drops something into the generic _DragAndDrop_-area for the _EditorGUI_ that I've made. And since the Area is supposed to be able to accept any `Type` that the actual GUI Code Implementation wants, then this callback method needs to be generic.

Comment: @devNull This is also why this won't be an issue. The caller is already defining the Type that they want to accept / be returned by the DragAndDrop-callback - thus it's up to them to actually look for that same type when they write the Callback Implementation :)

Comment: You _may_ have the wrong design. Does this method actually work if you use `as`? If it does, please consider accepting the answer that best answer your question. If it doesn't, I suggest you ask another question about how to do this, providing more details about how you desire to call `UpdateAudioClipsOnDragAndDrop`.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, it works with `as`. I was just curious why it actually worked, compared to the explicit cast. - I've marked @Rixment 's answer as the correct one, since it easily explained why it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you're casting down the inheritance tree, so it cannot be done implicitly as you and compiler doesn't know what type of object is being passed as type of T.

In the first case with direct casting you're saying to compiler that it HAS to be the type of AudioClip[] and in the second that it MIGHT be - if it's not, then null will be the result.

You can give a hint to compiler as you already do with the use of where keyword and specifying the class of T, so that even the first case will be non problematic to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks! Now I actually understand what the difference is between the explicit cast `(TypeToCastTo)` and using the `as`-keyword, and why the former gives a compile error, whilst the latter works in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

> And I was baffled, cause `AudioClip` derives from `Object`, so it shouldn't be an issue to cast to it.

Yes, casting from `Object[]` to `AudioClip[]` is ok (at least at compile time), but you are doing here is casting from `T[]` to `AudioClip[]`.

The generic constraint `T: Object` does not mean `T == Object`. It means that `T` is a subclass of `Object`. So it could be the case that `T == AudioClip`, or `T == Component` or `T == GameObject`. Hopefully you'll agree that there is no explicit conversion between `GameObject[]` and `AudioClip[]`. If you don't agree, here's the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-reference-conversions):

> The explicit reference conversions are:
>
> - ...
> - From an array_type `S` with an element type `SE` to an array_type `T` with an element type `TE`, provided all of the following are true:
>
>   - `S` and `T` differ only in element type. In other words, `S` and `T` have the same number of dimensions.
>   - Both `SE` and `TE` are reference_types.
>   - **An explicit reference conversion exists from `SE` to `TE`.**

Is there a explicit reference conversion from `T` to `AudioClip` then? [This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-conversions-involving-type-parameters) does not list such a conversion, so no.

The `as` operator however, works like this (excerpt from the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-as-operator) again):

> The `as` operator is used to explicitly convert a value to a given
>   reference type or nullable type. Unlike a cast expression, the `as` operator never throws an exception. Instead, if
>   the indicated conversion is not possible, the resulting value is null.
>
> In an operation of the form `E as T`, `E` must be an expression and `T`
>   must be a reference type, a type parameter known to be a reference
>   type, or a nullable type. Furthermore, at least one of the following
>   must be true, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - An identity, implicit nullable, implicit reference, boxing , explicit nullable, explicit reference, or unboxing conversion exists
>     from `E` to `T`.
> - **The type of `E` or `T` is an open type.**
> - `E` is the null literal.

The important point is that `as` will not produce an error if the type of `E` is an *open type*. According to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#open-and-closed-types) of the spec, `T[]` *is* an open type because it is an array type of a type parameter.

Why did the language designers design it like this? You'd have to ask them to know the true answer! :) My guess is that they wanted to have a stricter kind of casting and a less strict kind that doesn't crash when it fails.

---

In the end, though, even if you used `as`, this specific conversion will still fail (`audioClips` will be null) unless `T == AudioClip`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can't say I understood everything, but as you say, the `as`-conversion works as long as the `T[]` that is sent into the method is of the type AudioClip. I described it in another comment, but basically, the way the caller calls on the actual DragAndDropArea GUI Code, they will also specify what kind of Type they want/accept being dropped in that Area. So if they wanna do something with this callback, they should already know what type they've requested in the GUI Code :)