# C#: Any difference whatsoever between "(subtype)data" and "data as subtype" typecasting?

Tags: c#, .net, types, oop, casting

Assuming I have an instance of an object that I know belongs to a subclass of a certain subtype passed to me through a reference of a supertype in C#, I'm used to seeing typecasting done this Java-like way (Assuming "reference" is of the supertype):

```
if (reference is subtype){
subtype t = (subtype)reference;
}
```

But recently I've come across examples of what appears to be the same thing done this way:

```
if (reference is subtype){
subtype t = reference as subtype;
}
```

Are those two completely equivalent? Is there any difference?

Comment: Could you please put four spaces before code, so it gets marked up as code?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator

Comment: Did you even try to search for this question?

Comment: I searched but couldn't find those two other versions of the same question, thanks for pointing them.

Comment: Yes, I did try to search for that question BTW.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 - in fairness, he is adding the assurance that the reference actually is a subtype instance before performing the cast, which the other questions don't seem to address very well

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Although similar this is not quite the same (even though it is receiving similar answers).

Comment: It's amazing how the nifty feature of searching for similar questions as soon as you type the title doesn't avoid all the dupes we see everyday...

Comment: And how people upvote answers that dont answer the question... 10 upvotes for an answer taken from one of the other questions that has nothing to do with this question...

Comment: ok, guys, maybe the search feature isn't working well or favoring recent questions. I don't like asking dupes too, before asking I took the following precautions: - Search for both "typecast" + "C#" and "typecasting" + "C#" - Watched the "search as you type features", but those previous questions didn't appear. 
Now if you search for those terms this question appears. Should we refrain from asking questions in fear that they might have been asked before when we can't find them?

Comment: @Fabio: "Should we refrain...?" Certainly not. I don't mind people asking "similar" dupes (as opposed to "exact" dupes). Your question actually adds a new factor.

Comment: Whoever wrote the example you show which uses the 'as' keyword obviously does not understand why they are using it.  It is completely redundant.

Comment: ...And there is no check for null.

Comment: You guys that have been more active in this thread: I'm having a hard time picking the right answer. Some of them added interesting insights but I guess none has everything that was needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same used that way, but neither is the best option. You should do the type checking only once:

```
subtype t = reference as subtype;
if (t != null) {
   ...
}
```

Checking for null is more efficient than checking for type.

Comment: For reference types, this is *the* way to do it. For value types, you have to use `is`+(cast).

Answer (score 11):

The difference is one will throw an exception and the other one will return a null value if the casting is incorrect. Also, "as" keyword does not work on value type.

```
BaseType _object;

//throw an exception
AnotherType _casted = (AnotherType) _object; 

//return null
AnotherType _casted = _object as AnotherType;
```

**Edit:**

In the example of *Fabio de Miranda*, the exception will not be thrown due to the use of "is" keyword which prevents to enter in the "if" statement.

Comment: No, used as stated in the question neither will throw an exception.

Comment: Once you understand the difference, you don't really expect "as" to work on a value type, because value types are never null.

Comment: The only difference in the OP example are performance and the fact the second won't work with value types. The cast will always work.

Comment: @Guffa: True, but this answers the essence of the question. Incorrect casting with () throws exceptions; incorrect casting with "as" returns null. That's the major difference.

Comment: @Guffa: I agree with you that in his example, the code will not throw an exeception due to the use of "is" keyword. But the question title is "Difference between (subtype)data and data as subtype." I will add some clarification to include your comment in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

"as" tries to cast reference to subtype & returns null, if it fails.
Explicit casting when fails, throws InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not equivalent.  The first will work on any type but the second example will only work on reference types.  The reason why is the "as" operator is only valid for a reference type.

Comment: That's halfway correct - `as` won't work on vanilla value types, but it will work on nullable ones, and it's definitely a point of difference.

Comment: @Pavel, nullable types are so heavily special cased it's hard to consider them value types anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** As far I know (possbily outdated) "`as`" is faster then cast.

**2.** Neither of your examples are optimal. The optimal way is:

```
var v = reference as subtype;
if (v != null){
  // Do somthing.
}
```

In this way you do not have double-casting problem.

Comment: Code markup would help you get votes. Just put four spaces before your code.

Comment: I do not know why, but code want to be formated. I have tried 4 sapaces... Strange. Anywhere my answer is duplicate, so why bother?

Comment: @Mike - apparently if you start with an ordered list and put code beneath it, it treats it as part of the same line containing the nearest `<li>` - interesting...

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(VS.71).aspx

which says: "as" equals to:

expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null;

That means means second one is kind of too much.

Comment: With expression being evaluated only once! Beware of side-effects!

Answer (score -1):

One important thing about that is that, when using the as operator, such type should be nullable since, should it fail, it will return null. Whereas, using C-style casting, will throw an Exception when the cast can't be performed.

Comment: Well, it has to be because 'as' does not work for value types, and all reference types are nullable.

Comment: And how come it deserves a -1? I might be stating a fact but a fact is a fact.

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't downvote. You can't simply answer facts for being facts. The tooltip on the down arrow reads: "This answer is not helpful". That's the point.

Comment: I gave you the -1 because it doesn't make sense.  The program won't compile if the type after the 'as' is a value type, so why bother to say that at all?  Also, it did not explain the difference between the two before you edited the post.