# Different Cast Types in C#

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Casting: (NewType) vs. Object as NewType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype)
>   [Why is the C# “as” operator so popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-as-operator-so-popular)

Hey,

I know this may be a silly question but this doubt came to me today.

What is the difference between doing

```
String text = (String) variable;
```

and

```
String text = variable as String;
```

?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-as-operator-so-popular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cast can do three things:

- Perform a user-defined conversion
- Perform an unboxing conversion
- Perform a reference conversion

An `as` operation is almost always a reference conversion, the only exception being unboxing to a nullable type:

```
object x = "hello";
int? y = x as int?; // y is null afterwards
```

Then there's the behaviour with conversions which fail at execution time. So the differences are:

- Casts performing reference conversions or unboxing will throw `InvalidCastException` on failure; `as` will result in the null value of the target type instead
- Casts can perform user-defined conversions; `as` can't
- Casts can unbox to non-nullable value types; `as` can only be used for unboxing if the target type is a nullable value type

Answer (score 4):

`as` will return null if `variable` isn't actually of that type (`String` in this case).  The cast will throw an exception.

Comment: as will return null if variable isn't actually of that type **or a derived type** (String in this case). The cast will throw an exception.

Comment: Beat me to it. Keep in mind that `as` will not work on value types. `int i = obj as int;` will not compile.  The `as` keyword must be used with a reference type or nullable type as @Mehrdad Afshari said.

Comment: @Matt: it works. You need to use a nullable type: `int? i = obj as int?;`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to Eric Lippert's blog on casting in C#.  I'd summarize it, but it's pretty short and he'll explain it much better than me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

And here is his post on the cast operator:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to cast in C#.

This will try to cast the reference to a String reference. If the cast fails, it throws an exception:

```
string text = (String) variable;
```

This will try to cast the reference to a String reference. If the cast fails, it will return a null reference to be assigned to the variable:

```
string text = varible as String;
```

This will cast a string reference to an object reference, which is a safe casting as String inherits from Object:

```
object text = (object)"1337";
```

Casting to a parent class can also be done implicitly:

```
object text = "1337";
```

This will box a value inside an object, then unbox it to a plain value again:

```
int value = 42;
object boxed = (object)value;
int valueAgain = (int)boxed;
```

The boxing can also be done implicitly:

```
int value = 42;
object boxed = value;
int valueAgain = (int)boxed;
```

This will make a widening conversion from byte to int:

```
byte a = 42;
int b = (int)a;
```

The same works as an implicit conversion:

```
byte a = 42;
int b = a;
```

This will make a narrowing conversion from int to byte, throwing away the overflow:

```
int a = 512;
byte b = (byte)a; // b now contains 0
```