# Casting - What's the difference between "(myObject)something" and "something As myObject" in C#?

Tags: c#

I've encountered this a couple of times and been perplexed.

```
Cat c = new Cat("Fluffy");
return (Animal)c;

Cat c = new Cat("Fluffy");
return c as Animal;
```

What's the reason for both of these syntaxes to exist?

Comment: Try searching instead.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Comment: Hmm I did check the autocompleted dropdown for duplicate questions but it isn't always reliable :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `as` operator is a safe cast.  If the types are not compatible, `as` will return `null`.

The explicit cast, `(Animal)c`, on the other hand, will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the types are not assignment-compatible.

Also worth noting that `as` only works for *inheritance* relationships, whereas the explicit cast operator will work for value types...

```
decimal d = 4.0m;
int i = (int)d;
```

...and any other [explicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a(VS.80).aspx) defined on the type with `public static explicit operator`.  These won't work with `as`.

Comment: +1 could also benefit from mentioning that `as` can't be used to cast to a value type.

Comment: Great answer, especially like the link about explicit/implicit casting, valuable information to know.

Answer (score 6):

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88420.aspx

"Using the `as` operator differs from a cast in C# in three important ways:

1) It returns null when the variable you are trying to convert is not of the requested type or in it's inheritance chain, instead of throwing an exception.

2) It can only be applied to reference type variables converting to reference types.

3) Using as will not perform user-defined conversions, such as implicit or explicit conversion operators, which casting syntax will do.

There are in fact two completely different operations defined in IL that handle these two keywords (the castclass and isinst instructions) - it's not just "syntactic sugar" written by C# to get this different behavior. The as operator appears to be slightly faster in v1.0 and v1.1 of Microsoft's CLR compared to casting (even in cases where there are no invalid casts which would severely lower casting's performance due to exceptions)."

Answer (score 3):

With this:

```
return (Animal)c;
```

You are explicitly saying that c is of type animal, and if not something has gone wrong.

With this:

```
return c as Animal;
```

You are saying that you are pretty sure that c is of type animal, but maybe not all the time.

Eric Lippert talks about it in his blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The cast syntax, `return (Animal)c;` will throw an InvalidCastException if the object cannot be cast to the type `Animal`.  This is nice if you *know* it is an Animal, and if it is not, something has gone very wrong.

The `return c as Animal;` syntax will return null.  This is handy if you would like to avoid catching exceptions:

```
Cat c = GetAnimal("Fluffy");
if (c == null)
{
    AddAnimal("Fluffy");
}
```