# object casting in C#

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting: (NewType) vs. Object as NewType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype)

Just wanted to know which one is faster and what's the difference.

> MyClass test = someclass as MyClass;
>
> or
>
> MyClass test = (MyClass)someclass;

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the `as` keyword does not throw an exception when it fails and instead it fills the l-value with `null` whereas casting with brackets will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: And it is much preferable to have a meaningful exception now than a NullReferenceException later.  So I would say stick with a regular cast unless you handle the nulliness immediately after an 'as' cast.

Comment: Also note that you can't use the as keyword with value types.

Answer (score 1):

The `as` keyword will return `null` if the desired cast is not valid.  Explicit casting will throw an exception in that case.  Consequently, I believe the implicit cast (`as`) is slower, though it's likely negligible.

Comment: nope, `as` casting is way faster than prefix casting.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have a technical reason for that?

Comment: you can see the technical reasons in the codeproject link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Faster?  It probably isn't going to ever matter.  You'll have to wait until there is a scenario where your performance profiling application tells you to that the cast is taking too long.

Difference?

Will set *test* to **null** when *someclass* can't be cast to *MyClass*.

```
MyClass test = someclass as MyClass;
```

Will throw an exception when *someclass* can't be cast to *MyClass*.

```
MyClass test = (MyClass)someclass;
```

Answer (score 0):

`as` casting is faster than prefix casting, but doesn't produce reliable results, ie. it returns null if the cast can't be executed. You'll have to deal with that yourself. Prefix casting will throw an exception if `T1` can't be casted to `T2`.

See: [blog](http://gen5.info/q/2008/06/13/prefix-casting-versus-as-casting-in-c)

[image: as vs prefix]

See [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx)

Comment: I thought that as was slower....

Comment: gj with the downvote whoever that was.