# C#: Is there any Difference between (Type)Something vs Something as Type

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)
>   [Casting vs. using the as keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

In C#, whats the difference

```
var obj = (Array)Something
```

vs

```
var obj = Something as Array
```

Comment: This is a dupe of many [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr) here. Is no one ever reading the documentation these days?

Comment: first hit when searching this site for `[c#] typecast` showed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724051/what-is-difference-between-normal-typecasting-and-using-as-keyword-closed which in turn is closed as a dup of other questions. Voting for closing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first will throw a CastException if invalid. The second will only result in obj = null instead.

Comment: The second will result in true? :)

Comment: No the second will result in an object of the correct type or null. You are thinking of the `is` operator, Arcturus.

Comment: no, the second will result in obj variable not being assigned any value because the cast failed. Thus, obj will be null

Comment: I know Matt, but `obj = null` so `obj == null` is `true`. One = sign too many :)

Comment: I think danijels means that the second code example in the OP will mean that obj will equal null, or obj == null :)

Comment: exactly, Matt. I don't see the confusion here really. Looking at the smiley at the end of first comment, I can only assume the guy was trying to be cute...

Comment: Correct.. think nothing of it, just trying to be funny.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = (Array)Something
```

will throw an [InvalidCastExcpetion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) if `Something` not derived from `System.Array` or does not have a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) for `System.Array`. This can be used with value types and reference types.

```
var obj = Something as Array
```

will return `null` (`obj` will be `null`) if `Something` not derived from `System.Array` or does not have a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) for `System.Array`.  This can be used only with reference types. You'd need to [box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) you value type first.

Answer (score 1):

As well as Danijels answers

The first can be used with any type.

The `as` operator can only be used on reference types.