# Functions only from baseclass

Tags: c#, winforms

I´m making this game but I´ve run into a problem with the structures. I´ve made a class called Structure and other classes like Traps, Shelter, Fireplace inherits from this class. The tiles in the game have their own class(Tile) and have a list of Structures on that tile. I can succesfully build structures on tiles which are included in the list. The problem comes when I try to acces the functions from classes like Traps etc. it won´t work. I can only use the functions from the base class Structure.

List in Tile:

```
class Tile
{
     public List<Structure> Structures = new List<Structure>();
}
```

How I build a Trap or other building:

```
        bool anyFireplace = Bundle.map.tile[Bundle.player.X, Bundle.player.Y].Structures.OfType<Shelter>().Any();
        if (!anyFireplace)
        {
            woodlogsCost = 4;
            if (Bundle.player.Woodlogs - woodlogsCost >= 0)
            {
                Bundle.map.tile[Bundle.player.X, Bundle.player.Y].Structures.Add(new Shelter(Bundle.player.X, Bundle.player.Y));
                Bundle.player.Woodlogs -= woodlogsCost;
            }
        }
```

When I draw the Structures (here is where my problem is, note the comments)

```
foreach (Structure s in Bundle.map.tile[x, y].Structures)
{
   if (s is Fireplace)
{
   //This is the function from base class Strucure
   s.ColorBody(g, 10, x - minx, y - miny, 0, Brushes.Firebrick);

   // The function that I wan´t to use but can´t be used
   //s.ColorBody(g, x - minx, y - miny); 
}
if (s is Shelter)
{
s.ColorBody(g, 10, x - minx, y - miny, 1, Brushes.ForestGreen);
}
if (s is Sleepingplace)
{
   s.ColorBody(g, 10, x - minx, y - miny, 2, Brushes.Brown);
}
if (s is Trap)
{
   s.ColorBody(g, 10, x - minx, y - miny, 3, Brushes.Silver);
}
if (s is Barricade)
{
   s.ColorBody(g, 10, x - minx, y - miny, 4, Brushes.DarkOliveGreen);
}
}
```

Soo... I wonder how do I access the functions I wan´t to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the computer, `s` *is only* a `Structure`. If you want to call a specific method that only the `Fireplace` class has but the abstract class `Structure` does not have (e.g. `Fireplace` class might have a `BurnWood()` method that wouldn't make sense for a `Structure` to have), then you want to let the computer know that this `Structure` is actually *also* a `Fireplace` (for example). So you could do this by casting; for example:

```
((Fireplace)s).ColorBody(g, x - minx, y - miny);
```

or

```
(s as Fireplace).ColorBody(g, x - minx, y - miny);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724051/what-is-difference-between-normal-typecasting-and-using-as-keyword?lq=1) on the difference between casting and using the `as` operator.

Answer (score 6):

Add a virtual method to your base class;

```
public class Structure
{
   public virtual void ColorBody(Graphics g, int someParam1, int someParam2)
   {
       // do nothing in the base class
   }
}
```

and override the method in FireBody

```
public class FireBody : Structure
{
    public override void ColorBody(Graphics g, int someParam1, int someParam2)
    {
        // do something here for FireBody
    }
}
```

and if all classes inheriting from `Structure` needs it then make it abstract;

```
public abstract class Structure
{
   public abstract void ColorBody(Graphics g, int someParam1, int someParam2);
}
```

Comment: +1, or better yet make it `abstract`.  This will force derived classes to implement it.

Comment: This works great but so does Jasons answer so both of you got an +1. I see advantages in both ways so I wonder which one is best to use? Are there any performance difference or something?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about performance difference. There is basically none. But needing an overload to `ColorBody()` may indicate a better way to architecture your app. Perhaps multiple Color() functions that call each other in a chain instead of using just one `ColorBody()`? Example: Maybe a base `ColorStructure()` that is identical for all structures. Then `ColorSpecificStructure()` that exists for each structure _but is implemented differently_. If you can architecture this, then you don't need any casting hacks or switch statements. You would be able to call `structure.Color()`.

Answer (score 1):

As I can notice from your question that you have have two overloaded functions in the two classes i.e for base class and derived class you have different number function parameters

In this case you have to take support of [compile type polymophism](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/31365-Polymorphism-C.aspx) as shown below

```
 public BaseQueryClass
{
    public string QueryClassFunc(string mystring, int i)
    {
        return mystring + i.ToString();
    }
}

public QueryClassDerived : BaseQueryClass
{
    public string QueryClassFunc(string mystring)
    {
        return mystring;
    }
}
```

and you can call your methods as shown below

```
 BaseQueryClass qClass = new BaseQueryClass();
        qClass.QueryClassFunc("mystring", 1);

        ((QueryClassDerived)qClass).QueryClassFunc("test");
```

Hope I am not missing here anything