# the comparison between as and cast

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Anyone can give a comparison between as and cast?

Comment: See [Direct casting vs 'as' operator?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A straight cast will fail if the object being casted is not of the type requested.  An `as`-cast will instead return null.  For example:

```
object obj = new object();
string str = (string)obj; // Throws ClassCastException
```

However:

```
object obj = new object();
string str = obj as string; // Sets str to null
```

When the object being casted *is* of the type you are casting to, the result is the same for either syntax: the object is successfully casted.

Note specifically that you should avoid the "as-and-invoke" pattern:

```
(something as SomeType).Foo();
```

Because if the cast fails, you will throw a NullReferenceException instead of a ClassCastException.  This may cause you to chase down the reason that `something` is null, when it's actually not!  The uglier, but better code

```
((SomeType)something).Foo();
```

Will throw a ClassCastException when the object referenced by `something` cannot be converted to `SomeType`, and a NullReferenceException when `something` is null.

Comment: +1 my usual advice is:
If you are doing an "as" then the next line should be a null check.

Comment: @Simon: Good point.  I think that's what I usually do, but I've never simplified it to that simple statement.

Answer (score 1):

"as" don't throw exception and return null if cast is failed.

It works similar this code:

```
if (objectForCasting is CastingType)
{
   result = (CastingType)objectForCasting;
}
else
{
   result = null;
}
```

The good practice is to use checking for null after using as statement:

```
CastingType resultVar = sourceVar as CastingType;

if (resultVar == null)
{
   //Handle null result here...
}
else
{
   // Do smth with resultVar...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing an explicit cast differs from using the as operator in three major aspects.

The as operator…

1. returns a null if the variable being converted is not of the requested type nor present in its inheritance chain. On the other hand, a cast would throw an exception.
2. can be applied only to reference type variables being converted to reference types.
3. cannot perform user-defined conversions—e.g., explicit or implicit conversion operators. A cast could perform these types of conversions.

Comment: Point 2 is incorrect. You can use it for nullable value types too.

Comment: Copied verbatim without attribution from one of the answers here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2631380f-b926-4633-ba42-d3c019605e5b/cast-which-is-the-correct-way?forum=csharpgeneral