# How do I deserialize an object into a generic list?

Tags: c#, generics, serialization

I have the following deserialization function.

```
private object Deserialize(string file)
{
   var ret = new object(); 
   var fmt = new BinaryFormatter(); 
   using(FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)) 
   {
      ret = fmt.Deserialize(fs); 
   } 

   return ret; 
}
```

I call the function and cast it as a generic list of the expected type.

```
var list = Deserialize(file) as List<Something>;
```

But I get a `null` value. Debugging the code shows that the function works. The `result` object is a list.

Answer (score 0):

For one, `File.Open` does not have an overload that takes a single argument. At the very minimum, you need to specify the FileMode as well.

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(file,FileMode.Open)
```

Secondly, `Filestream` does not have a member method `Deserialize`, so `fs.Deserialize` is invalid.

To help you further, what kind of a file are you attempting to deserialize. CSV, XML...

Comment: Thanks, I deserialize a binary file,and it should be fmt not fs **private Object Deserialize(string file)
{
   Object ret=new Object();
   var fmt=new BinaryFormatter();
   using(FileStream fs=File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
   { 
      ret=fmt.Deserialize(fs);
   }   
   return ret;
}**

Comment: @PointedC, please edit your question and put the compilable code there, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Something> ret;
ret=(List<Something>)serializer.fmt(fs);
```

Comment: Oh thanks I use the above function in my OP because I have other lists (List<SomethingElse>...). Debug shows that the above function works, I get the ret value as expected but right after the line of the function call, the value return is null.

Comment: Well aside from the things xbonez pointed out, I don't believe there is anything we'd be able to tell from this.  If you're going to use this to deserialize various types then I would recommend using a generic method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your serialization?

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote a program that serializes/deserializes some data *based on the code you provided*, and it works fine.**

You said:

> But I get a null value. Debugging the code shows that the function works. The result object is a list.

There is a subtle difference between 2 casting operations in C#

```
string text = (string)GetString(); // throws exception if cannot be cast
string text = GetString() as string; // returns null if source cannot be cast
```

- [Casting: (NewType) vs. Object as NewType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype)

*Other than that, based on the limited amount of info that you provided, we won't be able to help you further troubleshoot.*

Can you narrow it down to the line of code that isn't working?  Are you sure that the serialization is working properly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Cereal
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string file = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "cereal.bin");

      List<string> namesToWrite = new List<string>();
      namesToWrite.Add("Frosted Flakes");
      namesToWrite.Add("Fruit Loops");
      namesToWrite.Add("Lucky Charms");
      namesToWrite.Add("Apple Jacks");

      Serialize(file, namesToWrite);

      List<string> namesToRead = Deserialize(file) as List<string>;;

      foreach (string name in namesToRead)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Serialize(string file, object stuff)
    {
      var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();

      using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create))
      {
        fmt.Serialize(fs, stuff);
      }
    }

    static object Deserialize(string file)
    {
      var ret = new object();
      var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();

      using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
      {
        ret = fmt.Deserialize(fs);
      }

      return ret;
    }
  }
}
```