# When to use () vs. 'as' to change type?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting: (NewType) vs. Object as NewType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype)
>   [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

```
//var gridView = (gridViewRow.NamingContainer as GridView); <-- works too
var gridView = (GridView)gridViewRow.NamingContainer;
```

My incomplete understanding of this is using `as` keyword can give `null` when using a cast `()` will throw an exception. My goal is to be able to ask myself "which way should I cast?" and know how to answer it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many times over like, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype

Answer (score 5):

It depends, but basically:

If you know and can guarantee that the object **is** the type you think it is then use `()`.

If there's a possibility that it could be something else then use `as` and check for `null`. In this case you'd have:

```
var realThing = someObject as MyClass;
if (realThing != null)
{
    ....
}
```

You can use `is` to guard the `()` which would result in:

```
if (someObject is MyClass)
{
    var realThing = (MyClass)someObject;
    ....
}
```

But this results in two conversions, rather than the one of `as` or the straight `()` cast.

This is where the "it depends" comes in. You'd have to decide on a case by case basis which was more appropriate. You might have coding standards to adhere to as well.

Comment: out of curiosity, what about using "is" operator to guard a use of ()? any different?

Comment: You shouldn't use "is" to guard, as then you will perform 2 conversions.  If you need that functionality, convert with "as" and check for null.

Answer (score 3):

The question is more of

> How do I want my code to deal with a dynamic cast failure?

If you have an implicit / explicit contract that `gridViewRow.NamingConainer` is in fact a `GridView` then an `()` cast is appropriate.  If the type is not a `GridView` it's violated a contract, an exception is thrown and the error will be apparent.  However if it's possible that it's not a `GridView` and you want to proactively handle the case then `as` is appropriate.

In this case it looks like you do have an implicit contract that it is a `GridView` and hence I would continue to use `()`.  If you went with `as` and the contract was broken you'd end up with a `NullReferenceException` which is not actually the problem.  The problem is the type wasn't a `GridView` as expected and hence `InvalidCastException` is much more appropriate

Comment: +1 for the tip to think about the clarity of meaning of the resulting exception in the error case

Answer (score 2):

The [C# Frequently Asked Questions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/) blog covers this in [What's the difference between cast syntax and using the as operator?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-cast-syntax-and-using-the-code-as-code-operator.aspx). There is a discussion of the [caveats](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/when-not-to-use-c-keyword.html) from Andrew Arnott that you might be interested in too.

Comment: Can you summarise the arguments here. If ever the links die there'd be no information in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is that if I know it is the type I am casting it to I use ()s. For example, I would use a direct cast inside a conditional which already checked the type. If I am not sure, I typically use 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that gridViewRow.NamingContainer is a GridView, yes, use (GridView) to cast. Clearly, the code that follows does not handle null, so if your assumption is wrong, you get an exception either way. Using (GridView) to cast will make the exception useful for you as the programmer, because the exception will show the line that has the bug in its stack trace.

If you do not know whether gridViewRow.NamingContainer is a GridView, you can combine the 'if (gridViewRow.NamingContainer is GridView) { ... (GridView)gridViewRow.NamingContainer ... }' in an 'as' conversion.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://gen5.info/q/2008/06/13/prefix-casting-versus-as-casting-in-c/), the difference lies in how errors in conversion are handled. To summarize:

- `()` will throw an exception if the cast is invalid, i.e, if the variable isn't a subclass of the cast.
- `as`, on the other hand, will return a null pointer instead, offering slightly better performance at the cost of harder debugging.