# difference between in-front type conversion and "as" conversion

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting: (NewType) vs. Object as NewType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype)
>   [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

What is the difference between these 2 types of conversion(as i've seen, they don't work both all the time) :

```
ClassA a = (ClassA)someClassObject;
```

and

```
ClassA a = someClassObject as ClassA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx (emphasis mine):

> The as operator is like a cast **except that it yields null on
>   conversion failure instead of raising an exception**. More formally, an
>   expression of the form:
>
> ```
> expression as type
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
> ```
>
> except that expression is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case an InvalidCastException will be thrown at runtime if the cast doesn't succeed. In the second case you will get `null` in the result variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first is casting - if `someClassObject` cannot be cast, an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown.

The second will not throw an exception, but `a` will be `null` if the cast does not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As will return null and cast will exception from memory