# Getting info on C# menu items after a click

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

Another question from a C# newbie- I would like to use a single function to respond to a list of choices offered in the menu. When I run in debug mode I can hover the mouse over sender and it is clear that sender has the information I need, both the index of the item in the menu and the text associated with it.  However, I have not figured out how to write code in a way that I get what I am looking for.  The following does not compile:

```
int device;
private void myMenuItemInputClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    device = sender.Index;
}
```

What I see when I put a breakpoint on myMenuItemInputClick and put the mouse over sender is:

> sender {Windows.System.Forms.MenuItem, Items.Count:0, Text:Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini}

Moving the mouse over the "+" sign so it becomes a "-" and a list of debug statements drops down shows that there is an item Index that is exactly what I want.  How do I write the code that will get the item I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the sender to MenuItem will possibly solve this problem.

```
int device;
private void myMenuItemInputClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    device = ((MenuItem)sender).Index;
}
```

The variation Bharath mentioned would be something like,

```
int device;
private void myMenuItemInputClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if(menuItem != null)
        device = menuItem.Index;
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  That did it.  Casts in C# operate in ways I don't completely understand yet.

Comment: No worries. Most event objects can be cast the same way.

Comment: Explicit type casting like `(MenuItem)sender` might throw exception. Better use `is` or `as` when conversion and check for null.

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype?lq=1) for `is` or `as` type cast

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `sender` object to the type you are working on. You should be able to fetch the properties.

E.g.

```
var menuItem= sender as MenuItem;
menuItem.Index
```